# Performance issue when zooming (Leaflet 0.7.3)

Tags: performance, leaflet, openstreetmap, zooming

I'm facing a performance problem with Leaflet (version 0.7.3). I'm working with an OSM map that I use to display a bunch of CircleMarkers linked by decorated Polylines (with arrow pattern every 25px). Loading take a little time but the main problem is that when I zoom the map I start facing severe lag (from the zoom level 16) and, beyond a certain limit (say 18 most of the time), browser just freeze and eventually crash (tested with chrome and firefox). I tried with a bunch of 1,000 linked markers, then I dropped to a set of around 100, but still the same concern... Of course, with 10 markers or less I don't have any problem.

Did you already face a similar trouble? How can I optimize Leaflet performances so that I can use an accurate zoom (beyond level 16) with more than 100 linked CircleMarkers ? I also wonder why performances are dropping so badly when zooming, while marker amount stay the same...

Thank you in advance for your answers,

Lenalys.

Cannot get the PolylineDecorator plugin to work on jsfiddle. 
But here is the code that generate markers :

Map initialization :

```
var map;

function initializeMap(){
  "use strict";

  var layer;
  var layer2;

  function layerUrl(key, layer) {
      return "http://wxs.ign.fr/" + key
          + "/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&"
          + "LAYER=" + layer + "&STYLE=normal&TILEMATRIXSET=PM&"
          + "TILEMATRIX={z}&TILEROW={y}&TILECOL={x}&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg";
  }

  layer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
  {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 18
  });

  layer2 = L.tileLayer(
    layerUrl(IGN_AMBIENTE_KEY, "GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS"),
    {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.ign.fr/">IGN</a>'}
  );

    var baseMaps = {
      "Terrestre": layer,
      "Bathymetrique": layer2
    };

    map = L.map('map', {
        layers: [layer],
        zoom: 8,
        center: [42.152796, 9.139150],
        zoomControl: false  
    });

   L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);

    //add zoom control with your options
    L.control.zoom({
         position:'topright' //topleft
    }).addTo(map);

    L.control.scale({
      position:'bottomleft',
      imperial : false
    }).addTo(map);


}
```

Data Sample :

var jsonData ={"12":[{"id_stm_device":"7","individual_name":"cerf3","latitude":"42.657283333333","longitude":"9.42362","temperature":null,"pulse":null,"battery":"20","date_time":"2015-03-17 15:37:12"},
    {"id_stm_device":"7","individual_name":"cerf3","latitude":"42.657381666667","longitude":"9.42365","temperature":null,"pulse":null,"battery":"20","date_time":"2015-03-17 16:42:16"},
    {"id_stm_device":"7","individual_name":"cerf3","latitude":"42.657381666667","longitude":"9.4236933333333","temperature":null,"pulse":null,"battery":"20","date_time":"2015-03-17 17:47:21"},
    {"id_stm_device":"7","individual_name":"cerf3","latitude":"42.657283333333","longitude":"9.4237383333333","temperature":null,"pulse":null,"battery":"20","date_time":"2015-03-17 19:57:23"}],
    "13":[{"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.61683","longitude":"9.4804633333333","temperature":"17.45","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 07:45:20"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.538858333333","longitude":"9.48169","temperature":"14.37","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 08:00:29"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.458748333333","longitude":"9.500225","temperature":"14.46","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 08:15:49"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.3302","longitude":"9.5374583333333","temperature":"15.19","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 08:31:05"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.170133333333","longitude":"9.5272116666667","temperature":"15.48","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 08:46:20"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.07959","longitude":"9.47688","temperature":"15.97","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 09:01:31"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.076163333333","longitude":"9.4828633333333","temperature":"20.42","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 09:16:59"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.07194","longitude":"9.4908866666667","temperature":"17.36","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 09:32:17"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.072583333333","longitude":"9.4901516666667","temperature":"17.36","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 09:47:32"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.07238","longitude":"9.4904266666667","temperature":"19.38","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 10:02:42"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.072298333333","longitude":"9.4904983333333","temperature":"17.46","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 10:17:55"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.095093333333","longitude":"9.5148383333333","temperature":"17.47","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 10:33:12"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.112881666667","longitude":"9.5133133333333","temperature":"19.3","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 10:48:23"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.112875","longitude":"9.513285","temperature":"22.71","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 11:03:57"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.141096666667","longitude":"9.5078216666667","temperature":"23.73","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 11:19:12"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.282186666667","longitude":"9.5505183333333","temperature":"18.97","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 11:34:28"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.405126666667","longitude":"9.531145","temperature":"20.71","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 11:49:42"},
    {"id_stm_device":"8","individual_name":"cerf5","latitude":"42.482063333333","longitude":"9.480665","temperature":"21.7","pulse":null,"battery":"80","date_time":"2015-04-08 12:05:07"}]}

```
var oJSON = JSON.parse(jsonData);



var colors = [
    "#400080",
    "#008000",
    "#EC7600",
    "#E40341",
    "#0D5E5E",
    "#919191",
    "#FF3C9D",
    "#A70A0E",
    "#00BFBF",
    "#7171FF"
  ];

var classes  = [
    "color1",
    "color2",
    "color3",
    "color4",
    "color5",
    "color6",
    "color7",
    "color8",
    "color9",
    "color10"
]; 


var lastMarkers = [];
var layers = new Array();
var polyline; 
var decorator;

window.graphicsDevices = [];
var offsetLatitude = 0.003333;
var offsetLongitude = 0.011666;
```

Marker instanciation :

```
function printGPSOnMap(oJSON){
  var nbKeys = 0;

  for (var key in oJSON) {
    nbKeys++;

    var classe = classes[(key-1)%classes.length]; 
    var color = colors[(key-1)%colors.length];

    var positionInfo = [];

    if (oJSON.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

          var aInfo = oJSON[key];
          var marker;
          var latlngs = Array();

          var startMarker = lastMarkers[key];
          if(startMarker !== undefined && startMarker != null) {

            var myIcon = L.divIcon({className:  "myCircle "+classe, iconSize : [ 20, 20 ] });
            startMarker.setIcon(myIcon);
            latlngs.push(startMarker.getLatLng());
          }
          for(var i = 0; i < aInfo.length; i++) {
               var oInfos = aInfo[i];
               var sIdIndividual = oInfos["id_individual"];
               var sLongitude = oInfos["longitude"];
               var sLatitude = oInfos["latitude"];
               var sTemperature = oInfos["temperature"];
               var sPulse = oInfos["pulse"];
               var sBattery = oInfos["battery"];
               var sDatetime = oInfos["date_time"];
               var sIndividualName = oInfos["individual_name"];
               var id_device = oInfos["id_stm_device"];

               var popupMsg = "...";

               latlngs.push(L.marker([sLatitude,sLongitude]).getLatLng());

               marker = new MyCustomMarker([sLatitude,sLongitude], {
                                        icon : L.divIcon({ 
                                           className : "myCircle "+classe + ((i == aInfo.length-1) ? ' myCircleEnd' : ''),
                                           iconSize : [ 20, 20 ]
                                        })
                                        });
                                        marker.bindPopup(popupMsg, {
                                               showOnMouseOver: true 
                                        });
                                        marker.bindLabel(key, {
                                               noHide: true,
                                               direction: 'middle',
                                               offset: [offset[0], offset[1]]
                                        });
              positionInfo.push(marker);
         }

         lastMarkers[key] = marker; 
      }

      if(latlngs.length > 1)
      {

      polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {className: classe, weight: 2,opacity: 0.4}).addTo(map);
      decorator = L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
        patterns: [
            // define a pattern of 10px-wide arrows, repeated every 20px on the line 
            {offset: 0, repeat: '25px', symbol: new L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 10, pathOptions: {fillOpacity:        
                 0.76, color: color, weight: 1}})}
        ]}).addTo(map);
     }

     if(!window.graphicsDevices.hasOwnProperty(key))
        window.graphicsDevices[key] = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < positionInfo.length; i++) {
        window.graphicsDevices[key].push(positionInfo[i]); 
        positionInfo[i].addTo(map);
        if(latlngs.length > 1){
          window.graphicsDevices[key].push(polyline);
          polyline.addTo(map);
          window.graphicsDevices[key].push(decorator);
          decorator.addTo(map);
        }
      } 
  }//foreach key

}
```

Code for the custom marker :

```
var MyCustomMarker = L.Marker.extend({

    bindPopup: function(htmlContent, options) {
    if (options && options.showOnMouseOver) {
      // call the super method
      L.Marker.prototype.bindPopup.apply(this, [htmlContent, options]);
      // unbind the click event
      this.off("click", this.openPopup, this);
      // bind to mouse over
      this.on("mouseover", function(e) {
        // get the element that the mouse hovered onto
        var target = e.originalEvent.fromElement || e.originalEvent.relatedTarget;
        var parent = this._getParent(target, "leaflet-popup");
        // check to see if the element is a popup, and if it is this marker's popup
        if (parent == this._popup._container)
          return true;
        // show the popup
        this.openPopup();
      }, this);
      // and mouse out
      this.on("mouseout", function(e) {
        // get the element that the mouse hovered onto
        var target = e.originalEvent.toElement || e.originalEvent.relatedTarget;
        // check to see if the element is a popup
        if (this._getParent(target, "leaflet-popup")) {
          L.DomEvent.on(this._popup._container, "mouseout", this._popupMouseOut, this);
          return true;
        }
        // hide the popup
        this.closePopup();
      }, this);
    }
  },
  _popupMouseOut: function(e) {

    // detach the event
    L.DomEvent.off(this._popup, "mouseout", this._popupMouseOut, this);
    // get the element that the mouse hovered onto
    var target = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;
    // check to see if the element is a popup
    if (this._getParent(target, "leaflet-popup"))
      return true;
    // check to see if the marker was hovered back onto
    if (target == this._icon)
      return true;
    // hide the popup
    this.closePopup();
  },

  _getParent: function(element, className) {

    var parent = null;

    if(element != null) parent = element.parentNode;

    while (parent != null) {
      if (parent.className && L.DomUtil.hasClass(parent, className))
        return parent;
      parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: It sounds more like some issue with the code in question, rather than a general Leaflet issue. Is it possible for you to post some code, ideally on jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: I edit my post with the code that generate markers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you gauged performance in [canvas mode](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-canvas)?
Use `L_PREFER_CANVAS = true` before initializing your leaflet map container.Might be able to help you possibly.

Comment: I already tried this snippet and, despite small performance gain, map continues lagging and freezzing after some zoom. I use custom marker instead of circleMarker, maybe the problem can come from it ?

Comment: I added in my post the code for "MyCustomMarker" object.

Comment: Have you tried using non-decorated vanilla polylines between the markers as opposed to what you are doing now?to try to understand where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Should have try it sooner... Nice guess, removing the decorators solved the problem, now the map is smooth whatever the zoom level. This is a plug-in so I should have instinctly head to it first. Anyway thank you for your contribution, have you an idea of how can I have arrowed links between two markers without sacrifying performances ?

Comment: Eventually I found this : https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath
and it works perfectly !